# How can I differentiate "command substitution" from "subshell" inside a script?

Tags: bash, subshell, command-substitution

I need to differentiate two cases: [( …subshell… )](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/grouping_subshell) vs [$( …command substitution… )](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

I already have the following function which differentiates between being run in either a command  substitution or a subshell and being run directly in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function setMyPid() {
    myPid="$(bash -c 'echo $PPID')"
}

function echoScriptRunWay() {
    local myPid
    setMyPid
    if [[ $myPid == $$ ]]; then
        echo "function run directly in the script"
    else
        echo "function run from subshell or substitution"
    fi
}

echoScriptRunWay
echo "$(echoScriptRunWay)"
( echoScriptRunWay; )
```

#### Example output:

```
function run directly in the script
function run from subshell or substitution
function run from subshell or substitution
```

#### Desired output

But I want to update the code so it differentiates between command substitution and subshell.  I want it to produce the output:

```
function run directly in the script
function run from substitution
function run from subshell
```

P.S. I need to differentiate these cases because Bash has different behavior for the built-in `trap` command when run in command substitution and in a subshell.

P.P.S. i care about `echoScriptRunWay | cat` command also. But it's new question for me which i created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22221635/751932).

Comment: If none of your standard file descriptors are a terminal, that *could* be an indication that you are running in backticks, but that's a vague heuristic in the first place, and also there is no way to know if the entire script is in backticks, or just the current function.

Comment: Are you aware that pipelines appear to be subshells or command substitution? For example, each of: (1) `echoScriptRunWay | cat`, (2) `cat /dev/null | echoScriptRunWay` and (3) `cat /dev/null | echoScriptRunWay | cat` report 'subshell or command substitution'? Do you care what is reported for these cases? Also, your `setMyPid()` function is 3 lines more complex than necessary: `setMyPid() { myPid=$(bash -c 'echo $PPID'); }` is sufficient. In fact, the whole function is probably not really necessary; you could write the command substitution directly into the `if` condition in `echoScriptRunWay`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for usefull comment. since bash has no differ pipe and subshell for built-in `trap` command i care only for detect command substitution from these cases. I tested and function could be really simpler - so i simplify code in the question. Although my initial code looks more understandable

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference in behavior for `trap`? A command substitution is essentially just a subshell that masquerades as a parameter, one whose value is the standard output of the subshell.

Comment: You can replace your function `setMyPid` with a test for `$BASHPID`, which differs from `$$` for all subshells including command substitutions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was wrong about `trap` inside pipe... But it is new question so i created new http://stackoverflow.com/q/22221635/751932 . @chepner i created code to see difference between `trap` inside different using ways it's available here: http://pastebin.com/VTB4vrDC

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can reliably test if a command is run inside a command substitution.

You could test if `stdout` differs from the `stdout` of the main script, and if it does, boldly infer it might have been redirected. For example

```
samefd() {
    # Test if the passed file descriptors share the same inode
    perl -MPOSIX -e "exit 1 unless (fstat($1))[1] == (fstat($2))[1]"
}

exec {mainstdout}>&1

whereami() {
    if ((BASHPID == $$))
    then
        echo "In parent shell."
    elif samefd 1 $mainstdout
    then
        echo "In subshell."
    else
        echo "In command substitution (I guess so)."
    fi
}

whereami
(whereami)
echo $(whereami)
```

Comment: this code fail for case: `( whereami; ) 1>/tmp/tmp.txt` + also $BASHPID is not available under bash from OSX

Comment: @Speakus: Sure, it only tests for a redirection of `stdout`, which can be caused by basically anything. I didn't claim it's correct. :-) And yes, `BASHPID` requires bash 4. The `exec {mainstdout}>&1` thingy also requires a somewhat recent bash, although I don't know the version where this feature was introduced.